# SSRS Chart dosen't scale well

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a problem with the graph in Reporing services.
It is poorly scaled on the X axis, especially towards the end of the axis.

When checking the data from Query and making a chart in Excel, the data is correct.
Please compare the two screenshots (Reporting Services vs Excel) with exactly the same data.

I'm already try to change scope in RunnigValue and result it's the same.

[This is chart from Reporting services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRxwc.jpg)

[This is the chart from Excel for the same data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr2ix.jpg)

I need to try to show the same Chart as Excel but always I have the same in reporing services, I already check the query and it's for 100% OK.